# Calling a Class Fragment which extends Fragment from a MainActivity Class which extends Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How do I call a class which extends a fragment from a class which extends an activity, I have tried looking through various tutorials and stacks questions but when I try to implement the FragmentManager...etc.
I get a error on the line fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.LinearLayout1, fragment); Stating 
'Cannot resolve method add(int, com.example.angrywords.AccountDetailsFragment)'

I'm fairly new to android so any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

My MainAcivity.class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRetrieveHttpData, View.OnClickListener {
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    Button logoutbtn;
    Button Optionsbtn;
    private String mUserName;
    private String mPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the ActionBar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Set Layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(this, "username", mUserName);
        SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(this, "password", mPassword);

        logoutbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutbtn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

        Optionsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionsButton);

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                AccountDetailsFragment fragment = new AccountDetailsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.LinearLayout1, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        };

        Optionsbtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void NewPuzzleButtonClicked(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.newPuzzleButton) {
            //handle the click here
            startNewPuzzleActivity();
        }
    }

    public void SavedPuzzleButtonClicked(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.savedPuzzlesButton) {
            //handle the click here
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

My AccountDetailsFragment.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccountDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    Button changePasswordbtn;
    Button unregisterbtn;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v;
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account, container, false);
            changePasswordbtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.changePasswordbtn);
            unregisterbtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.unregisterbtn);

            TextView mName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.account_details_name_textview);
            String mFirstName = SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(getActivity(), "first_name", "First Name");
            String mLastName = SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(getActivity(), "last_name", "Last Name");
            mName.setText(mFirstName + " " + mLastName);

            TextView mUsername = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.account_details_username_textview);
            mUsername.setText(SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(getActivity(), "username", "Username"));

            TextView mPassword = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.account_details_password_textview);
            mPassword.setText(SharedPreferencesWrapper.getFromPrefs(getActivity(), "password", "Password"));

            changePasswordbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogFragment changePasswordFragment = new ChangePasswordDialogFragment();
                    changePasswordFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DIALOG_CHANGE_PASSWORD");
                }
            });
            unregisterbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogFragment unRegisterFragment = new UnregisterDialogFragment();
                    unRegisterFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DIALOG_UNREGISTER");
                }
            });
         return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

    }
```

And my activity_main.xml (if it helps)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="label main welcome"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentUserTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="label_main_sub"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.22" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log out"
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="316dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newPuzzleButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="NewPuzzleButtonClicked"
            android:text="New Puzzle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savedPuzzlesButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resume Saved Puzzle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/optionsButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Options" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are your import statements for your activity and fragments in both classes ?

Comment: I have included the imports now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your `MainAcivity` is extended from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` or `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and your `AccountDetailsFragment` is extended from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and your `FragmentManager` is the result of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Okay, I have tried to implement both of your ideas and changed the extends to `FragmentActivity`, then changed the extend to `ActionBarActivity`. neither of these worked but when changing the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `android.app.Fragment` it works but then I get an issue further down as to regards to the `getFragmentManager()` in my `AccountDetailsFragment` on line `unRegisterFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DIALOG_UNREGISTER");` stating Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager , java.lang.String)' is there a work around or a fix via a different import?

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue, not in the prettiest of ways but by implementing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` to the original statement in my MainActivity. Thank you for your opinion and support. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the type of Fragment that you are using. In the activity you have imported the standard FragmentManager which deals with the standard Fragments whereas your AccountDetailsFragment is of type v4 Fragment.